# Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets_SentryUpload FAILED

Tags: react-native, apk, sentry, react-native-sentry

I'm facing this issue when compiling APK in react-native,

This issue happens only when generating a release APK and the app works fine on debug mode.

It seems that the path to global node modules is wrong ( Not in Desktop ).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by following this steps:

1- Installing sentry-cli globally

```
sudo npm install -g @sentry/cli --unsafe-perm
```

2- Login in sentry with the sentry cli installed by

```
sentry-cli login
```

3- Updating my android/sentry.properties with the new token generated

```
defaults.url=https://sentry.io/
defaults.org=my-organization
defaults.project=my-project
auth.token=new_token
```

Answer (score -4):

I have fixed this by synchronizing with Gradle files.

Comment: Can you put the steps of the solutions? Tried syncing the gradle. Still the issue is there. Tried several things.

Comment: @SaheshAbeysinghe it's been a long time since I fixed that, did you try re-install the module and synchronizing with Gradle files?